# How to extract specific image meta for all images?

Tags: images, google-maps, geo-data

Been hitting my head against a wall for a couple weeks... I'm working on modifying a geotagging Wordpress plugin called Thesography. I have notified the developer of my past enhancements, and they are OK with it because this plugin is licensed under the terms of the GNU General Public License.

Currently the plugin will return a mini popup Google map for a single post, with a single image. I am looking to expand upon it to have another function which will display 1 large Google Map. This larger map will have all my geotagged images as pinpoints Then, using the Google Maps API, also display a thumbnail and post title for the specific image and pinpoint.

Onto the code:

Here is a snippet of the current code from the plugin. This snippet which retrieves the image data from the database for the specific image. As you can see, this code works for the current post. How can it be modified to include all images from all posts?

```
    if (is_null($imgID)) {
    $images = get_children(array(
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'ASC'
        ));
    if ($images) {
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $imgID = $image->ID;
        }
    }
}

$imgmeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($imgID);

if ($imgmeta)
{
if ($imgmeta['image_meta']['latitude'])
    $latitude = $imgmeta['image_meta']['latitude'];
if ($imgmeta['image_meta']['longitude'])
        $longitude = $imgmeta['image_meta']['longitude'];
if ($imgmeta['image_meta']['latitude_ref'])
     $lat_ref = $imgmeta['image_meta']['latitude_ref'];
if ($imgmeta['image_meta']['longitude_ref'])
        $lng_ref = $imgmeta['image_meta']['longitude_ref'];

$lat = geo_single_fracs2dec($latitude);
$lng = geo_single_fracs2dec($longitude);
if ($lat_ref == 'S') { $neg_lat = '-'; } else { $neg_lat = ''; }
if ($lng_ref == 'W') { $neg_lng = '-'; } else { $neg_lng = ''; }

$latlng = $neg_lat . number_format($lat,6) . ',' . $neg_lng . number_format($lng, 6);
```

And here's a sample snippet of the Google Maps API that I need to fit this latitude, longitude into. It will contain the latitude, longitude, the image source URL and the title of the post it displays in. That way someone can hover over a pinpoint, see the image, then click it to read more.

```
  var point = new GLatLng(43.91892,-78.89231);
  var marker = createMarker(point,'<a href="http://#>The Title of the Page</a><br><img src="http://image.jpg" width=150 height=100>')
  map.addOverlay(marker);
```

It's a fun one! I have been hitting my head against the wall and have come up blank each time I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all Images:

```
$all_images = get_posts( array(
     'post_type' => 'attachment'
    ,'numberposts' => -1
) );

foreach ( $all_images as $img )
    echo $img;
```

---

**Some notes:**

- You can use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.extract.php) to make your code shorter:

  ```
  extract( $image['image_meta'], EXTR_SKIP );
  echo $latitude;
  ```
- Use [Yoda Conditions](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#Yoda_Conditions).
- When writing php on one line, you can also use shorthand php:

  ```
  // Instead of 
  if ($lng_ref == 'W') { $neg_lng = '-'; } else { $neg_lng = ''; }
  // Write Shorthand
  $neg_lng = 'W' === lng_ref ? '-' : '';
  ```
- And stay to STRICT type checks:

  ```
  // Instead of just checking if the value is met,...
  if ( 'a' == $b )
  // ...also check if the value has the same type:
  if ( 'a' === $b )
  ```

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm still struggling. When I put in your "Get All Images" code, I am given an error in the logs: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.

So I used a var_dump() on $all_images, and quite a bit of information is returned. More than I expected. Is there a way to filter that information down? Or is that the job of the extract code?

Comment: The error is normal, as I `echo`ed the object. You'll have to access the parts of your object (the ones you need) with `echo $img->ID;` for example. Just take a look at your var_dump for what you can use.

Comment: Got it. Last question (I think) Now that we have a list of IDs, can you share the code that would extract the lat/long out of the metadata for each ID? I put in the extract snippet you provided, but it didn't return anything. Perhaps it's my newbieness shining through on this one.

Comment: Just loop through `$all_images` and build in your `foreach()`-loop something like `$all_w_meta[] = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $img->ID );`. Then access the new array and do whatever you need - see `extract()` for ex. Anyway that's plain php, so you might be better off consulting php.net function reference (linked ↑).

Comment: Is it also possible to find the post that the image ID is attached to using this foreach() loop?

Comment: I guess it's `comment_post_ID`. But please, just take a look at your DB Tables via phpMyAdmin or take a look at the DB description in the Codex.

Comment: Yes, I have been looking through phpMyAdmin, and the Codex. Haven't found anything that works (yet). Including comment_post_ID. I will keep RTFM'ing

Comment: The Codex has DB schemata. Btw: Just test everything comments column that has `ID` in its name.